# Dirichlet problem of complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

$\Omega=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<2, |z-1|>1\}$

I have to find a harmonic function $\phi$ such that $\phi=1$ on the outer boundary and $\phi=3$ in the inner boundary and $(z\neq 2)$

How do I map the region $\Omega=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<2, |z-1|>1\}$ to a simpler suitable domain for this problem  by a Mobius transformation?

Here the simpler domain is not specified. 
I tried to map to the concentric circles. But I am not sure. 
Any hints ?

Comment: Try a parallel strip. You can't have concentric circles because $\Omega$ is simply connected, and an annulus isn't.

Comment: Okay, yes sounds good.